# PlotLines on Date-Axis: (intermediate value).concat is not a function

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to add a plotLine to my chart, but always get this error:

```
(intermediate value).concat is not a function
```

I've prepared a jsfiddle: (intermediate value).concat is not a function

Any suggestions, what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take look at examples: http://jsfiddle.net/ge3fg/ http://jsfiddle.net/47zgw/

```
 plotLines: [{
            color: '#FF0000',
            width: 2,
            value: 5.5
        }]
```